# How to implement zooming with seekbar in SurfaceView Camera in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working on Surface-Camera-Preview, and want to implement zooming control with seekbar, already done with pinch zooming, so is there any way to to control it with seekbar? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set zoom with pinch zooming, you can use `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` to set zoom for camera:

```
seekbarZoom = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarZoom);
    seekbarZoom.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "progress:"+progress);

            // YOur code here in set zoom for pinch zooming, sth like this
            if(mCamera.getParameters().isZoomSupported()){

                Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                params.setZoom(progress);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Code shared by RoShan Shan is way to do it, but if you don't set max value of the SeekBar you will get lots of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`  from users due to not setting `seekbarZoom.setMax(params.getMaxZoom())`. Because default max of the SeekBar is 100 but maxZoom on many devices is less than 100.

Comment: How to implement same for camera2 api

Comment: Dear BalaramNayak, float maxZoom = (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM))*10;